# Sencha Touch List with Model and Store

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, sencha-touch

I am looking for a tutorial / sourcecode for a sencha touch list with a model and a store. I am facing some issues with Sencha Touch 2.2.1.

Model:

```
Ext.define("DeviceAPIFramework.model.OfferModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: "description",  type: "string" },
            { name: "id", type: "string" }
        ]
    }
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define("DeviceAPIFramework.model.OfferStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        storeId: "offerStore",
        model:'DeviceAPIFramework.model.OfferModel'
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
offerStore.add({description: 'test', id: 'my id'});
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#offersListHomeView')[0].update();
```

View:

```
Ext.require("DeviceAPIFramework.model.OfferStore");
var offerStore = Ext.create("DeviceAPIFramework.model.OfferStore");

Ext.define ........... 
{
    xtype: 'list',
    width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 1200,
    height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 350,
    title: 'test',
    itemId: 'offersListHomeView',
    store: offerStore,
    itemTpl: '{description} {id}'
}
```

Image:

[image: Image of List]

After executing the code from the controller, a new row gets appended, but also a weird undefined text on the upper left corner of my list. Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

I also don't like the variable offerStore outside the view. If I put it in the controller, the view is nagging.

Comment: post screen shot of list.. so that the question will be more clear...

Comment: @Viswa I uploaded a screenshot of the list. Sorry that I forgot it.

Comment: Every thing looks fine, I can't find what causing the undefined text in each list item and there is no need for  'Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#offersListHomeView')[0].update();'.. also update method in list is deprecated.

Comment: you can find why undefined text is coming by inspect element in browser.. check the generated html

Comment: @Viswa thanks for the tip debugging with the inspect element.
http://oi41.tinypic.com/4l68td.jpg There is one div element with "undefined". I used the new method setHTML(), update is also using this, and because I passed no parameters it appended undefined ... If u want, post an answer and I will approve + upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The undefined is coming from this line:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#offersListHomeView')[0].update();
```

update is decrapted(I wrote it, because I was developing once with an old Sencha Touch version and this update was necessary) and will call setHtml(), because we are passing no arguments it is settings "undefined", which will be shown in our view. In the new sencha version, you can simply delete this line.

I also managed the global store problem with this code in the controller:

```
launch: function() {
    this.offersStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'DeviceAPIFramework.model.OfferModel'
    });

    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#offersListHomeView')[0].setStore(this.offersStore);
},
```